# HTML/XHTML TEL: and USSD String

Tags: html, ussd, tel

Hi All I'm trying to get the `<a href='tel:*120*5xxxx#' />` to work but it does not like the USSD part. Is there a way to use tel: with a [USSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USSD) string ?

PS. xxxx above represents numeric value's and yes i have tried urlencoding.

Comment: What the *hell* are you talking about?

Comment: Ahh, makes a bit more sense now. It would be helpful if you would explain your problem in layman's words though. I have no idea what an USSD string is, and I'm too lazy to look it up.

Comment: As far as I can see from the `tel:` RFC, the above is valid. What software are you using to open the URL?

Comment: Don't forget, "#" and "*" are reserved characters and you will need to URL encode them. Usually as <a href="tel:%2A120%2A5555%23"> You can find out more about percent encoding at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, Iphone doesn't permit that html links have in them **USSD** codes, they are ignored. 
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660951/how-to-use-tel-with-star-asterisk-or-hash-pound-on-ios) explain it better maybe.

Android from it's side, has different behaviours. I usually `escape` the string that contain the USSD, it depends on the lenguage you are programming it on, i mean, in javascript could be `escape()` or `urlencode()` for example if you are on php. Anyway, doing some tests, it seems that Android phones could or could not follow the links with **USSD** codes this because it has been found a vulnerability on some phones (galaxy s3 for first) where you could reset the phone with a proper **USSD** code, without any user prompt. Thes has lead to a patch from Android (as far as I know), but I don't know what happens next.